# Need to create a package with a specific number in either the protocol header or payload

Tags: networking, wireshark

Unfortunately I'm not too familiar with Wireshark and in our recent homework we are supposed to create a pcap file which includes a specific number. In order to create that pcap file we are supposed to use the search function of Wireshark to find by string in packet bytes and export the result with the specified number in either the protocol header or the payload. How am I supposed to go about this?

Answer (score 0):

Well, this was way easier than I thought. All I needed to do was to create a connection to a FTP server, listen to that connection in Wireshark and then transfer a textfile with the number in it/named after it, in plain FTP in ASCII mode.